# There is a unique isomorphism from $\langle \Bbb Q,<,+,\cdot,0,1 \rangle$ to an ordered field

Tags: proof-verification, ordered-fields

> Let $\mathfrak{Q}=\langle \Bbb Q,<,+,\cdot,0,1 \rangle,\mathfrak{A}=\langle A,<,+,\cdot,0',1' \rangle$ be ordered fields where $\Bbb Q$ is the set of rationals, and $f,g$ be isomorphisms from $\mathfrak{Q}$ to subfields of $\mathfrak{A}$. Then $f=g$.

Does my attempt look fine or contain logical flaws/gaps? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

It suffices to prove that $f(p)=g(p)$ for all $p\in\Bbb Q$ and $p>0$.

It is easy to prove that $f(0)=g(0)=0'$ and $f(1)=g(1)=1'$.

For $p\in\Bbb Q$ and $p>0$, $p=\dfrac{m}{n}$ for some $m,n\in\Bbb N$.

- $f(p)=f\left(\dfrac{m}{n}\right)=\dfrac{f(m)}{f(n)}=\dfrac{f(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{m\text{ times}})}{f(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}})}=\dfrac{\underbrace{f(1)+\cdots+f(1)}_{m\text{ times}}}{\underbrace{f(1)+\cdots+f(1)}_{n\text{ times}}}=\dfrac{\underbrace{1'+\cdots+1'}_{m\text{ times}}}{\underbrace{1'+\cdots+1'}_{n\text{ times}}}$
- $g(p)=g\left(\dfrac{m}{n}\right)=\dfrac{g(m)}{g(n)}=\dfrac{g(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{m\text{ times}})}{g(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}})}=\dfrac{\underbrace{g(1)+\cdots+g(1)}_{m\text{ times}}}{\underbrace{g(1)+\cdots+g(1)}_{n\text{ times}}}=\dfrac{\underbrace{1'+\cdots+1'}_{m\text{ times}}}{\underbrace{1'+\cdots+1'}_{n\text{ times}}}$

It follows that $f(p)=g(p)$ and thus $f=g$.

Comment: Yes. It's ok. Or you can show from $f(0)=g(0)=0'$ and $f(1)=g(1)=1'$  and by induction on $|n|,$ that $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$ and also  that $f(n)\ne 0' $ for all  $0\ne n\in \Bbb Z....$ Then for $m,n\in \Bbb Z$ with $0\ne n,$ we have $f(n)f(m/n)=f(m)=g(m)=g(n)g(m/n)=f(n)g(m/n),...$ so $f(n)f(m/n)=f(n)g(m/n)$ with$ f(n)\ne 0'$,  so $f(m/n)=g(m/n)$.

Comment: Hi @DanielWainfleet, I actually did what you suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066226/the-smallest-subfield-of-an-ordered-field-is-isomorphic-to-langle-bbb-q) :)